# IE8 Emulator check

Tags: internet-explorer-8, emulation

Could someone go to this  url: http://www.barbadostravelbuddy.co.uk/demo/?r=register
in IE8 and tell me what the submit on the bottom  of the right hand column looks like, please?

I suspect my emulator isn't working correctly on this point of CSS.

It should have white text on a blue gradient but my emulator is showing with a white block. In IE7 (the real version) this does display correctly and it seems unlikely IE8 would regress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE8 result here :
http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/7784/screenie8.png

Comment: Thanks for that - it looks like I was hoping.

Answer (score 0):

What emulator are you using? Would suggest you to use [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). It uses the actual COM object of Trident (the Internet Explorer rendering engine) and hence seems quite reliable.